# Python logging: how to represent newlines in the format string in a logging config file?

Tags: python, logging, config, newline

I'm configuring my Python logging from a file (see http://www.python.org/doc//current/library/logging.html#configuration-file-format ).

From the example on that page, i have a formatter in the config file that looks like:

```
[formatter_form01]
format=F1 %(asctime)s %(levelname)s %(message)s
datefmt=
class=logging.Formatter
```

How do i put a newline in the "format" string that specifies the formatter? Neither `\n` nor `\\n` work (e.g. `format=F1\n%(asctime)s %(levelname)s %(message)s` does not work). Thanks

Comment: new lines in logging ? Please don't do it. The log file will be very difficult to grep.

Comment: @fabrizioM True,but that's irrelevant for this question.

Answer (score 9):

The `logging.config` module reads config files with [`ConfigParser`](https://docs.python.org/2/library/configparser.html), which has support for multiline values.

So you can specify your `format` string like this:

```
[formatter_form01]
format=F1
    %(asctime)s %(levelname)s %(message)s
datefmt=
class=logging.Formatter
```

Multilines values are continued by indenting the following lines (one or more spaces or tabs count as an indent).

Answer (score 7):

The logging configuration file is based on the [`ConfigParser`](http://docs.python.org/library/configparser.html) module. There you'll find you can solve it like this:

```
[formatter_form01]
format=F1
   %(asctime)s %(levelname)s %(message)s
datefmt=
class=logging.Formatter
```

Answer (score 0):

My best bet would be using a custom formatter (instead of logging.Formatter)... For reference, here's the source code for logging.Formatter.format:

```
def format(self, record):
    record.message = record.getMessage()
    if string.find(self._fmt,"%(asctime)") >= 0:
        record.asctime = self.formatTime(record, self.datefmt)
    s = self._fmt % record.__dict__
    if record.exc_info:
        # Cache the traceback text to avoid converting it multiple times
        # (it's constant anyway)
        if not record.exc_text:
            record.exc_text = self.formatException(record.exc_info)
    if record.exc_text:
        if s[-1:] != "\n":
            s = s + "\n"
        s = s + record.exc_text
    return s
```

It's pretty clear to me that, if self._fmt is read from a text file (single line), no escapping of any kind would be possible. Maybe you can extend from logging.Formatter, override this method and substitute the 4th line for something like:

```
s = self._fmt.replace('\\n', '\n') % record.__dict__
```

or something more general, if you want other things to be escaped as well.

EDIT: alternatively, you can do that in the **init** method, once (instead of every time a message is formatted). But as others already pointed out, the ConfigParser support multiple lines, so no need to go this route...

Answer (score 0):

This might be an easy way:

```
import logging
logformat = """%(asctime)s ... here you get a new line
    ... %(thread)d .... here you get another new line
    %(message)s"""
logging.basicConfig(format=logformat, level=logging.DEBUG)
```

I tested, the above setting gives two new lines for each logging message, as it shown in the codes. Note: `%(asctime)s` and things like this is python logging formatting strings.

Answer (score 0):

```
import logging
logformat = "%(asctime)s %(message)s\n\r"
logging.basicConfig(level=logging.DEBUG, format=logformat,filename='debug.log', filemode='w')           
logging.debug (Your String here)
```

Debug text in the file will be written with new line.

Answer (score 0):

Just add "\n" before the closing apostrophe of basicConfig function

```
logging.basicConfig(level=logging.DEBUG, format=' %(levelname)s - %(message)s\n')
```

[image: log message with newline after the message]